# How hide " section " on blogger when no widget inside it

Tags: html, xml, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views, google-blogger-api

I need help Plz.
I wanna hide section on blogger when no widget inside it.. or widget is invisble.. and I use this code.

```
<b:if cond='data:widgets.notEmpty'>
  <b:section id='box-one'/>
</b:if>
```

but not work for me  .. any one have a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you this code:

```xml
<b:if cond='(data:widgets count w => w.sectionId == "box-one") > 0'>
  <b:section id='box-one'/>
</b:if>
```

where `box-one` is the section id